# Django TemplateSyntaxError Could not parse the remainder: error when using {% if MyModel.objects.filter(id=maxid).values('col2') = something %}

Tags: django, django-models, syntax-error

In Django, im trying to get a different button shown in html based on what value is in the latest created object of a model.

my HTML code is:

```
  {% if MyModel.objects.filter(id=maxid).values('col2') = something %}
  <button id="Button 1">Button 1</button>
  {% else %} 
  <button id="Button 2">Button 2</button>
  {% endif %}
```

but when i reload the screen, Django gives me this error message

TemplateSyntaxError at /col2/
Could not parse the remainder: '(id=maxid).values('col2')' from 'MyModel.objects.filter(id=maxid).values('col2')'

Comment: You should be handling this in your view in get_context_data

Comment: in the if condition use `==`